# ggplot theme argument for axis arrows suddenly not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, axis

I have a custom ggplot theme that I have been using for a while now. This week I started getting an error when making plots using this theme stating that `plot.new has not been called yet`

I've traced the error to an `axis.line()` argument which i've used before to turn my axis lines into arrows. I was able to reproduce the error below, but i'm confused why this is happening now. Does anyone know why this could be happening or possibly provide some alternatives to changing axis lines to arrows?

Eg:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- mtcars

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black", arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "lines"), type = "closed")))
```

EDIT:

loading the graphics library (`library(graphics)`) fixed the issue temporarily. However knitting the markdown file produces the same error as above. It seems my example is not reproducing the error, however it's persisting on my computer even after re-installing RStudio AND updating all packages.

Comment: Use `dev.off()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where would I include that? after calling the plot? Will I need to do that every time I create a plot in my markdown?

Comment: Do it once in the console and see if your plot works. With your code for me it is possible to get axis with arrows.

Comment: I get an error ```cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)```. I'll try restarting everything.

Comment: OP, I'm trying, but I cannot reproduce your error message.  I do not think it's lacking `dev.off()`, since it's already "shut off" based on the `cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)` message.  (If you have a plot, then type `dev.off()`, then try to send it again, you'll also see that message).  I wonder if there's something that got messed up with either the `grid` or `graphics` packages.  Try installing those packages again (`install.packages("grid")` and `install.packages("graphics")`) and seeing if that fixes the issue.  You can also try installing `ggplot2` again.

Comment: After updating all packages and reinstalling R, I loaded graphics ```library(graphics)``` and it worked. Thanks so much for your help!